# how to find first div images?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html:

```
<div id="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
         <div>
           <img /><img /><img /> <!--target these images only-->
         </div>
         <div>
           <img /><img /><img />
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</dvi>
```

How can I target that images from `#test`?

`.find('#test div:first-child img')` /* likely to this but seems wrong statement*/

---

How about to use like ?

$('#test img').parent('div').parent('div').children('div:first img');

Comment: I would recommend giving those images or their containing div a class so you can easily select them.

Comment: Use this: `$('#test div:first>img')`

Comment: @Mr_Green doesn't work....

Comment: also @NavinRauniyar If somebody has found the correct answer you might want to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on the parent selector containing `#text`

You're trying to use find so:

```
.find('#test div:first-child img')
```

Will indeed work if its something like this

```
$('body').find('#test div:first-child img')
```

But, if you want to use it as a normal selector try this:

```
$('#test div:first-child img')
```

Not sure what you're after though :/

**Updated answer**

Simple:

```
$('#test > div > div > div > div:first img')
```

Comment: works in this case but not the best though. check Ivan's solution.

Comment: @Mr_Green the OP has since updated his question, so pleased remove the -1

Comment: This works for OP but again you are calling all the `img` tags in that selected div. which could be the nested images too.

Comment: if it works for the OP, then where is the issue? That is all I am trying to fix, not some other issue created out of thin air :p Maybe start a new question

Comment: cool man, I was just trying to say you that this is the best `$('#test > div > div > div > div:first > img')` for OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').find('div').has('img')[0].find('img')
```

UPDATE:
This needed a bit more tweaking :)

```
var sdf = $('#test div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('img').size() > 0;
})[0];
$(sdf).children('img').css({'border': 'red 1px solid'})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwCCU/1/

Note:
First version caught all divs that are parent of div that has img so [0] was not the targeted div. Second version got only the divs that are direct parents of img so [0] contains first of those :)

Comment: if it has `img` then no need to use `find`. just use `children` instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
$("#test div:has(> img):first img")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eb5sA/